# deleting article does not delete its associated tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

I have implemented blog where I have many to many associations between article and tag. When a article is crated, it would have one to many tags. When I delete article from my application, it does delete its associated tag. I have set

```
has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :tags, through: :taggings , :dependent => :destroy
```

like this in article.rb(model). Do I need to do something else.

tag.rb

```
  class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings
end
```

How to get tag deleted when its associated article is deleted from db. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your `tag.rb`, use

```
belongs_to :article
```

rather than your current setup

Comment: hi, If I use your suggestion, It will destroy my has many through relation. is not ? there is many to many relation between article and tag.